# Does a VM guest system runs only when the VM's process is scheduled on the host?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, scheduling

I'm working on preparing an enterprise software package for running on the cloud, but I'm facing the issue that the software package runs as a real-time process on our current deployments. No one is really sure whether it's really necessary for the system, but they all heavily recommend doing so.

Running on a cloud service, however, our VM will share a host with dozen other (maybe hundreds?), and even though I can set the process to be scheduled at real-time inside the VM, the VM itself will still have normal priority on the host. Is that correct? Is the virtualization software scheduled as any other process on the host?

Comment: Talk to your cloud vendor. If they pin your VM to CPU(s), and if they lock qemu (if that's what they're using) in memory so that there's no paging activity, the guest should be consistently responsive, but you'll really need to test it.

Comment: What do you mean by *runs as a real-time process* (i.e. how did you configure it? On a linux kernel real-time processes do past through the scheduler just like any other, they just get something like a priority).  Several could services offer dedicated servers, i.e. explicitly offer a package where your server will not share resources (although proper dedicated servers tend to be expensive).

Comment: @grochmal Yes, I mean exactly that: Processes with a high priority inside the guest (in particular, who set themselves as high priority with `sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_RR, {sched_priority: 99})`).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Hm I guess that would be doable, but in that case we'd rather rent the bare metal servers themselves. I'm already aware that there's no real solution to this problem with common public VM clouds, I just want to know if my conjecture is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the host is concerned, a VM is one process that is scheduled like any other process. In the end, each processor (each core) can only be running one program at a time. The host's scheduler decides which one it is.

As far as I know, none of the virtual machine technologies that are typically used on cloud services offer real-time guarantees. It's definitely possible to make virtual machines with real-time guarantees, but there's a cost — the other processes get less CPU time. The cost/benefits typically don't match what cloud hosting aims for, which is to amortize resources between many contenders such that processors don't stay idle too long.

If you want real-time guarantees, that's going to be a fundamentally different service from basic cloud hosting, and one that you'll need to pay for. As putting multiple real-time processes together tends to require a holistic view to make sure that all of them meet their deadline, you'll most likely end up running your stuff the way you want, on dedicated hardware.

Cloud and real-time does strike me as a strange combination. A task running on a cloud service is only completed once you've downloaded the response, and you typically wouldn't have any service guarantees for the communication between the endpoint that needs the response in real time and the cloud service. Real-time computations normally have to be kept within a network perimeter under your control, where you have throughput and latency guarantees.

Comment: It's an old system and we're working on packaging it for customers, running on the cloud, but I was really interested about the host scheduling part, and you were right on spot. Thank you!